# Recursively breaking out arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

```
{ 
    "ServiceCurrentlyPlaying": {
        "fn": "Slideshow-41958.mp4",
        "apps": {
            "ServiceCurrentlyPlaying": {
                "state": "stopped"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How would I break anything named ServiceCurrentlyPlaying out of an array? (from `json_decode(file, TRUE)`) This is probably an easy question to anyone that knows it, but I've been trying to do something that doesn't involve manually hardcoding each array into another empty array (like with a lot of `foreach ($outer as $inner)` is what I'm doing but having issues since the amount of nesting varies)

Note: I have to deal with around 41958 files that all have different levels of nesting, different amounts and structure, so ..

Result I'd like would be:

```
{
    "fn": "Slideshow-41958.mp4",
    "apps": {
    "state": "stopped"
    }
}
```

Thanks, very much appreciated.

Comment: There is also [`array_walk_recursive`](http://php.net/array_walk_recursive), maybe it is of use in your situation.

Comment: but any key taht holds array will not be passed to the function

Comment: i think that is json object convert it into php array

Comment: "Any key that holds an array will not be passed to the function"? I tried one that just prints out $key and $item and I don't see ServiceCurrentlyPlaying at all unfortunately

Comment: you can use `array_values` but it return all the `array` (parent) with numbers keys 0, 1, ... well if u need just the first $array_from_array_values[0]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite optimized maybe, but this is the idea.

```
$data = json_decode('{ "ServiceCurrentlyPlaying": { "fn": "Slideshow-41958.mp4", "apps": { "ServiceCurrentlyPlaying": { "state": "stopped" } } } }', true);
$modifiedData = breakArray($data);

function breakArray($arr) {
  if(is_array($arr) && sizeof($arr)>0) {
    $buffer = array();

    foreach($arr as $key=>$value) {
      if($key==="ServiceCurrentlyPlaying") {
        if(is_array($value)) $buffer = array_merge($buffer, breakArray($value));
      } else {
        $buffer[$key] = (is_array($value) ? breakArray($value) : $value);
      }
    }

    return $buffer;
  } else {
    return $arr;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

USE

```
 $array=json_decode($jsondata);
    $i=0;
    foreach($array as $key=>$arr)
    {
     $out[$i]['fn']=$arr['fn'];
    $out[$i]['apps]=$arr['apps']['ServiceCurrentlyPlaying']

    $i++;
    }
```

Comment: And what happens then? What to do next then?

Comment: May as well just unset arrays manually, still looking up ways to do this, so far nothing :(